# Can I strike backward directly?

Tags: carrom

I am an amateur player of carrom and I have seen in tournaments players striking backward their striker to pocket the coins behind the hand.

Is this allowed?

Comment: Having played a bit more, I believe the difference here is whether you're on fixed sides or moving around. In tournaments, players are seated and have a fixed baseline to play from, and they take backwards shots. In casual play people often move around and choose their baseline; in such a game you only shoot forward.

Answer (score 1):

According to the rules of ICF (international carrom federation) you can strike backwards directly. It is popularly known as thumbing as you use your thumb to strike the coins behind the baseline.  Watch any international tournament matches on youtube. you will notice players thumbing.

Answer (score 0):

It is against the [rules](http://www.mastersgames.com/rules/carrom-rules.htm):

> **Striking**
>
> - For each strike, the player must position the striker within the
>   baseline OR on one of the two circles at either end of the baseline.
> - A striker within the baseline must touch both the front line and the
>   rear line.
> - The striker may not "cut the moon" - be placed partially
>   within the baseline and partially within the circle.
> - The player must flick the striker with one finger so that it crosses the front baseline - **it is not permitted to flick backwards or horizontally**.
> - A piece that is on or behind the front baseline must not be struck by
>   the striker until the striker has crossed the front baseline.
> - In striking, the player's hand or arm must not cross the diagonal foul
>   lines at either end of the baseline.

Comment: Welcome to Board and Card Games Stack Exchange. I took the liberty to Improve your answer by adding a reference to the rules and quote the relevant part. Next time, please put some more effort into your answer.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe I'd personally much rather you submitted your content as a separate answer. While this is a good answer, it's nothing like the answer that was given, so it seems weird to me to upvote Ravi's answer purely because of your work.

Comment: @Samthere, Probably, but I like the positive encouragement theory.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is allowed now by ICF but in India a lot of people on the streets are yet to adopt the change

Comment: Welcome to Board & Card Games! Do you have any sources (links) to back this up?